# How can I save indentation depth in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

Is possible to save the indent tags for bulleted lists? I don't want to have to constantly reset the borders for every new list I make. It's possible so save every other setting, so why not this?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the definition of "indent tags". What are you referring to?